# Calculating Maximum Hamming Distance between N Strings for Each String

Tags: java, algorithm, binary

I am trying to write a program which takes n binary strings of equal length and outputs the maximum hamming distance for each string when compared to the rest. My current solution uses a nested for-loop approach to bruteforce the maximum by comparing the characters in a string, but I want to make it more efficient using hamming distance. Any suggestions?

As stated, I tried using a nested for-loop approach that compared all the characters in all strings to each other and saving the maximum character difference.

Comment: Since you have working code, the question might be better suited for Code Review. Note that Code Review requires a copy of working code in the question. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour , see the   "What topics can I ask about here?" and "How do I ask a good question?" links near the top of that page.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to [The Curse of Dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality).

Suppose that we have `n` random binary strings of length `k` with `n` and `k` both large.  The `O(k n^2)` brute force algorithm is as good as you're going to get.  With overwhelming probability, every pair of strings has a Hamming distance in the range `k/2 + O(sqrt(k) log(n))`.  So you are unlikely to be able to use information obtained from comparing one string to learn anything about comparing with others.

To see this, note that a single bit comparison between 2 strings is a random variable, 0 or 1 with equal odds.  This has an average of `1/2` and a standard deviation of `1/4`.  Add up k and you get approximately a normal distribution with average `k/2` and variance `k/4`. The standard deviation is therefore `sqrt(k)/2`.

From [bounds on the tail of normal distribution](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/norm-dist-bounds/) we can derive that the probability of a random pair being `t` or more standard distributions away from average are `O(exp(-t^2/2) / t)`.  Let's set `t = 2 log(n)`.  The odds of being more than `t` standard distributions away are now

```
O(exp(t / 2) / t)
    = O(exp(-(2 log(n))^2 / 2) / (4 log(n))
    = O(exp(-2 log(n)) / (4 log(n)))
    = O(n^(-2) / (4 log(n))
    = O(1 / (4 log(n) n^2))
```

Therefore with `O(n^2)` pairs, the odds that any are more than `2 log(n)` standard deviations off is `O(1 / log(n))`.

As `t` increases, these odds drop very, very quickly.  For example if we set `t` to `4 log(n)` the odds for a single pair being that far in the tail drop to `O(1 / (log(n) n^8))`, and any pair in the group is `O(1 / (log(n) n^6))`.  Therefore with overwhelming probability, all pairs are within `O(log(n))` standard deviations.  A standard deviation is `k/4`.  And therefore all are in the range `k/2 + O(sqrt(k) log(n))`.